How to hide every scrollbar at once with injected CSS (kepping the element scrollable)
EDITED
I'd like to hide every single scrollbar inside webpages, keeping each scrollable element always scrollable.
I'm working on an injected Javascript file, which adds a style element into every webpage that I visit, but some pages have more than one scrollbar and my tag can't style all of them.
Injected script:
const styleTag = document.createElement("style")

styleTag.textContent = `

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        appearance: none !important;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
`

document.head.appendChild(styleTag)

The user @Yogi found out the problem:

Your css works fine on default scrollbars. It doesn't work on elements where the page is already styling the scrollbar. For example, the electron page applies style .thin-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar within a media query. Consequently, your css is ignored even if you apply important.

A Minimal, Reproducible Example


.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 20rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.spacer {
  height: 50rem;
  width: 50rem;
}

@media(pointer:fine) {
  .thin-scrollbar {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
  }
  .thin-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    /* placeholder */
  }
  .thin-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    /* placeholder */
  }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  appearance: none !important;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    OK - scrollbars hidden<br> 
    This box has default scrollbars
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    Bottom
  </div>
  <div class="box thin-scrollbar">
    FAIL - scrollbars visible<br> 
    This box uses a styled scrollbar
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    Bottom
  </div>
</div>



So, I need that my style tag can overwrite the "already styled scrollbars" in the page, too.
Does someone know how to make my injected CSS the most important of the document?

Comment from staging ground from @CBroe : There is no reason why this should apply to some scroll bars on a page only - if they are indeed native scroll bars, and not perhaps something added via JavaScript. Can you give an example of an element on a specific page, where this is not working?

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].   This needs to include appropriate (minimal) HTML and CSS (maybe javascript if scrollbars added dynamically) so that the issue can be reproduced in the question itself.

@fdomn-m   I hope the edit is enough, sorry it's my first question here

@Yogi In the Staging Ground I took as an example the webpages of youtube.com and electronjs.org/docs/latest, which both have one or more siderbars with not editable scrollbars. I don't think these are specific elements, just divs

If there are <iframe> elements in your document, then they'll use their own styles, making any CSS rule defined in the parent DOM useless. If you wish for its content to inherit the CSS rules, then you must use the seamless attribute (it will inherit the CSS rules, but it can have its own CSS rules which will override the inherited CSS rules). You can also try using the attribute scrolling="no" to hide the main scrollbar. See https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe for more details.

@Yogi thank you for the information! Now i'm going to edit my question

@Yogi thanks again for the edit, now i know how to add code snippets too
